# pass inherited template struct as an function argument

Tags: c++, struct

I have a template struct `MyStruct` in `Template.h`.
I want to pass `MyStruct` as an argument in a function in another header file `header.h`. Something likes this:

```
 //Template.h
template <class T1, class T2>
struct MyStruct{
  int myInt;
  unordered_map<pair<T1, T1>, T2>;
};
```

Now I want to put this struct to one function in my class:

```
//header.h
#include "template.h"
class MyClass {
  public:
    MyClass();
    virtual ~MyClass();
    void myFunction(int, MyStruct myStruct);
  private:
    int myValue;
};
```

I also want to call `myFunction` in third file `myCpp.cpp`, its head file `myCpp.h` has a shared pointer named `std::shared_ptr<MyClass> sharedPtr;`
In `myCpp.cpp`, I called :

```
sharedPtr->myFunction(int, myStruct);
```

where `myStruct` is returned by the function above it.
So, my question is, how to make this work? I tried to add define the struct again in `header.h` but it showed: prototype for ... does not match any in class.

Comment: You are going to need to specify type arguments for MyStruct. For example MyStruct<int, int>. You can also use a template function if you want to take any type.

Comment: myFunction has to be a template function because MyStruct is a template struct. 
`template<class T1, class T2> void myFunction(int, MyStruct<T1, T2> myStruct);`

Comment: I really want to close this question as it does not meet the stackoverflow standards. Alas, I don't have the rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your member function `myFunction` a template member function:

```
class MyClass {
  public:
    MyClass();
    virtual ~MyClass();
    template <class T1, class T2>
    void myFunction(int, MyStruct<T1, T2> myStruct);
  private:
    int myValue;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add template argument in the MyStruct parameter.
Do `MyStruct<type1 type2>` myStruct instead. You're good to go.